# Fill backup drive with newest files

Tags: windows, synchronization, backup

I have about 12TB (and growing) library, distributed over 3 HDDs, of video files and I would like to back them up to an external harddrive. I am using Windows 10 Pro.

My backup drive has only 8TB and I would like to always backup the newest 8TB of video files. So far I have tried about 10 sync tools but none of them allowed me to copy files according to creation date.

Also with robocopy I haven't found a way to copy only the latest 8TB of files.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 batch scripts for you that do what you have asked for. The main difference between them is, that the 1st script is using [`where`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) to locate all the files which will use the timestamp of the last change. To use another timestamp e.g. last access or time of creation you have to use the 2nd script I attached which uses [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html).

**1.
Batch script using `where` to locate files:**

It takes minimum 2 arguments:
**Usage: `batch.bat <dst> <src_1> [<src_...> <src_n>]`**

It uses the `where /r <src_n> * /t` command which will build a list of all files in all subdirectories with a timestamp of the last change in the following format:

```cmd
<size>   <date>          <time>    <file name>
  5397   11.07.2017      14:32:09  C:\Users\...\foo.txt
 10860   12.07.2017      11:25:15  C:\Users\...\bar.log
```

The timestamp is of last change if you need the time of the creation or last access take the 2nd batch script below which is using `dir` as there is the possibility to choose between different timestamps.

This output will be written (without the column `size`) into a temporary file under the temp dir `%TEMP%` (will be deleted automatically after script) for every source that is passed via the argument list. The complete temporary file is sorted by the date and time, newest first.

This sorted output will be used to copy it into the destination folder.

**Example:**

Current directory in `cmd` is `C:\...\Desktop`):
`batch.bat "backup_folder" "F:\folder" "F:\folder with space"`

Current directory somewhere:
`batch.bat "C:\...\Desktop\backup_folder" "F:\folder" "F:\folder with space"`

The `C:\...\Desktop\backup_folder` will contain 2 folders `folder` and `folder with space` which contain all files of these source folders after the scripts operation.

In your case the batch script would copy only 8 TB of the newest files because then the drive will be full and the batch script will exit because it recognizes copy errors.

**The batch script:**

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Check if at least 2 arguments are passed
set INVARGS=0
if [%1] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%2] == [] set INVARGS=1
if %INVARGS% == 1 (
   echo Usage: %0 ^<dst^> ^<src_1^> ^<src_...^> ^<src_n^>
   goto :EOF
)

rem Store Carriage return character in CR (used for spinner function, see below)
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

rem Set temp file name
set "uniqueFile=%TEMP%\%0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

rem Set destination path and shift to next argument
set "dstpath=%~1"
shift

rem Store src_1 to src_n arguments into src array
set idx=0
:again
rem If %1 is blank, we are finished
if not [%1] == [] (
   if not exist "%~1" (
      echo The following source folder doesn't exist:
      echo    "%~1"!
      echo The program will terminate!
      goto :end
   )

   pushd "%~1"
   set "src[%idx%]=!cd!"
   if [!src[%idx%]:~-1!] == [\] (
      set src[%idx%]=!src[%idx%]:~0,-1!
   )
   set /a idx=%idx%+1
   popd

   rem Shift the arguments and examine %1 again
   shift

   goto :again
)

rem Build command string:
rem where /r "src_1" * /t ^& where /r "src_..." * /t ^& where /r "src_n" * /t ^& break"
set "command="
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set src[') do (
   set "command=!command!where /r "%%s" * /t ^& "
)
set "command=!command!break"

echo "Command: ^<!command!^>"

rem Clear temp file and write files to copy in it
break>"%uniqueFile%"
for /f "tokens=2,3,4,* delims= " %%F in ('!command!') do (
   call :spinner
   echo %%F %%G %%H %%I>>"%uniqueFile%"
)

rem Open the built file list
echo File list will be opened...
%uniqueFile%
rem Ask user if copying should start
echo Should this files copied into %dstpath%? (Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Answer?:%=%
if not [%INPUT%] == [y] (
   if not [%INPUT%] == [Y] (
      goto :end
   )
)

set "dstpathPart="
rem Sort files newest first (last changed timestamp)
for /f "tokens=3,* delims= " %%F in ('type "%uniqueFile%" ^| sort /r') do (
   rem Build destination part from source folder names
   call :buildDestinationPath dstpathPart "%%F %%G"

   rem Prepend the destination folder
   set "dstFile=!dstpath!\!dstpathPart!"

   rem Make directories that doesn't exists
   for %%F in ("!dstFile!") do set "directory=%%~dpF"
   if not exist "!directory!" ( mkdir "!directory!" )

   rem Copy files and echo it
   echo copy /y "!file!" "!dstFile!"
   copy /y "!file!" "!dstFile!"
   echo.

   rem If copying failed exit program
   if errorlevel 1 (
      echo Copying failed... Maybe there is no more space on the disk!
      echo The program will terminate!
      goto :end
   )
)
goto :end


rem Function definitions
:buildDestinationPath
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set src[') do (
   rem Go into folder e.g.: C:\src_1\ --> C:\
   pushd "%%s"
   cd ..
   rem file contains full path of the where command
   set "file=%~2"

   rem Remove trailing space
   if "!file:~-1!" == " " (
      call set "file=%%file:~0,-1%%"
   )

   rem remove src folder from file to make it relative
   rem e.g. C:\src_1\foo\bar\file1.txt --> src_1\foo\bar\file1.txt
   call set "dstpathPart_temp=%%file:!cd!=%%"

   rem Switch back to origin folder
   popd

   rem If the folder name changed the substring taken was right so take next
   if not [!dstpathPart_temp!] == [!file!] (
      set "%~1=!dstpathPart_temp!"
      goto :next
   )
)
:next
goto :EOF

:spinner
set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
set "spinChars=\|/-"
<nul set /p ".=Building file list... !spinChars:~%spinner%,1!!CR!"
goto :EOF

:end
del "%uniqueFile%"
goto :EOF
```

---

**2.
Batch script using `dir` to locate files:**

It takes one more argument so that you need minimum 3 arguments:
**Usage: `batch.bat <timeordering> <dst> <src_1> [<src_...> <src_n>]`**

It will generate the same list as explained above but with the help of the `dir` command. The `dir` command takes the following parameter which is the `<timeordering>` parameter of the script:

```cmd
/tc Creation
/ta Last access
/tw Last written
```

**The batch script:**

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Check if at least 2 arguments are passed
set INVARGS=0
if [%1] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%2] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%3] == [] set INVARGS=1
if %INVARGS% == 1 (
   echo Usage: %0 ^<timeordering^> ^<dst^> ^<src_1^> ^<src_...^> ^<src_n^>
   goto :EOF
)

rem Store Carriage return character in CR (used for spinner function, see below)
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

rem Set temp file name
set "uniqueFile=%TEMP%\%0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

rem Set timeordering and destination path and shift to next argument
set "timeordering=%~1"
shift
set "dstpath=%~1"
shift

rem Store src_1 to src_n arguments into src array
set idx=0
:again
rem If %1 is blank, we are finished
if not [%1] == [] (
   if not exist "%~1" (
      echo The following source folder doesn't exist:
      echo    "%~1"!
      echo The program will terminate!
      goto :end
   )

   pushd "%~1"
   set "src[%idx%]=!cd!"
   if [!src[%idx%]:~-1!] == [\] (
      set src[%idx%]=!src[%idx%]:~0,-1!
   )
   set /a idx=%idx%+1
   popd

   rem Shift the arguments and examine %1 again
   shift

   goto :again
)


rem Clear temp file and write files to copy in it
break>"%uniqueFile%"
rem call commands with all sources:
rem call :getFileInformation /TC "src_1\*"
rem                          /TW
rem                          /TA
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set src[') do (
   call :getFileInformation %timeordering% "%%s\*" "%uniqueFile%""
)

rem Open the built file list
echo Unsorted file list will be opened...
%uniqueFile%
rem Ask user if copying should start
echo Should this files copied into %dstpath%? (Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Answer?:%=%
if not [%INPUT%] == [y] (
   if not [%INPUT%] == [Y] (
      goto :end
   )
)

set "dstpathPart="
rem Sort files newest first (last changed timestamp)
for /f "tokens=3,* delims= " %%F in ('type "%uniqueFile%" ^| sort /r') do (
   rem Build destination part from source folder names
   call :buildDestinationPath dstpathPart "%%F %%G"

   rem Prepend the destination folder
   set "dstFile=!dstpath!\!dstpathPart!"

   rem Make directories that doesn't exists
   for %%F in ("!dstFile!") do set "directory=%%~dpF"
   if not exist "!directory!" ( mkdir "!directory!" )

   rem Copy files and echo it
   echo copy /y "!file!" "!dstFile!"
   copy /y "!file!" "!dstFile!"
   echo.

   rem If copying failed exit program
   if errorlevel 1 (
      echo Copying failed... Maybe there is no more space on the disk!
      echo The program will terminate!
      goto :end
   )
)
goto :end


rem Function definitions
:buildDestinationPath
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set src[') do (
   rem Go into folder e.g.: C:\src_1\ --> C:\
   pushd "%%s"
   cd ..
   rem file contains full path of the where command
   set "file=%~2"

   rem Remove trailing space
   if "!file:~-1!" == " " (
      call set "file=%%file:~0,-1%%"
   )

   rem remove src folder from file to make it relative
   rem e.g. C:\src_1\foo\bar\file1.txt --> src_1\foo\bar\file1.txt
   call set "dstpathPart_temp=%%file:!cd!=%%"

   rem Switch back to origin folder
   popd

   rem If the folder name changed the substring taken was right so take next
   if not [!dstpathPart_temp!] == [!file!] (
      set "%~1=!dstpathPart_temp!"
      goto :next
   )
)
:next
goto :EOF

:getFileInformation
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d %~1 "%~2"') do (
   for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%b in ('dir %~1 "%%a" ^| findstr /l /c:"%%~nxa"') do (
      echo %%b %%c %%a>>"%~3"
      call :spinner
   )
)
goto :EOF

:spinner
set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
set "spinChars=\|/-"
<nul set /p ".=Building file list... !spinChars:~%spinner%,1!!CR!"
goto :EOF

:end
del "%uniqueFile%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Hi @hausii if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.